# Swift: Convert JSON String to Array of Custom Object with ObjectMapper

Tags: json, swift

I am currently using the ObjectMapper for Swift (see: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/) to convert a `String` from a HTTP Request to an object of a custom class. The JSON I get from the request is a JSON Array, and I would like to convert this to an `Array` from type `CustomObject`.

I have tried it like this:

```
var object = Mapper<Array<CustomObject>>().map(string: json)
```

But then I get an error: `Can not find member 'map'`.

How should this be done?

Edit: this is my `CustomObject` Class, from now called `ProductVariant`:

```
public class ProductVariant: Mappable {

    /* Attributes */

    public var id = 0
//    var size : Size = nil
    public var SKU = ""
    public var stock = 0
    public var numberOfDefects = 0

    /* Constructors */

    public init?() {
        // Empty Constructor
    }

    required public init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    /* Methods */

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        SKU <- map["SKU"]
        stock <- map["stock"]
        numberOfDefects <- map["numberOfDefects"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess you haven't implemented the " `Mappable` protocol as given  in the ObjectMapper documentation. Can you post  your `CustomObject` mapping if this is not the case?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have implemented the `Mappable` protocol, and I have updated my question.

Comment: If you are using ObjectMapper to map HTTP responses, you should consider using [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). It is a simple extension to Alamofire which automatically converts your responses into swift objects using ObjectMapper.

Full disclosure: I am the author of both ObjectMapper and AlamofireObjectMapper

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have found a solution, which seems to be working:

```
var list: Array<ProductVariant> = Mapper<ProductVariant>().mapArray(string: json)
```

When I loop through the array, it gives me the correct attributes for the `CustomObject`.

My mistake was that I tried to put the `Array` in the type of the `Mapper`, as shown in my question.

Comment: Thanks, I looking for this. May I know the source you found ? I cannot find in their github page.

Comment: @Megamind I just figured it out with trial on error, cant remember that I have found it anywhere online

Comment: Just a little note that Mapper has multiple mapArray functions. You want to hit the `mapArray(JSONString: String)` one **not** the `mapArray(JSON: AnyObject?)` one.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
let products = Mapper<ProductVariant>().mapArray(JSONString: json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the object mapper pod and import ObjectMapper in your file